# Why Httpclient returns always the same result C# PCL?

Tags: c#, httpclient, portable-class-library

I am using HttpClient PCL Class library. But When First Time I Get the JSON result It return correct data. After that HttpClient returns the same JSON result again and again for one URL till I close the application and start it again. My code looks like that

```
public class HttpService : IHttpService
    {
        public async Task<TResponseType> GetAsync<TResponseType>(string method, string parameters = null) where TResponseType : class
        {
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.ServerUrl + method + parameters));
            using (var client=new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    "c2Rzb2w6c2Rzb2w5OQ==");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponseType>(result);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow up on this or find a solution? I've got the same problem using the pcl within a Windows Phone project.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in an answer for a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118123/windows-phone-8-httpclient-get-method-returns-strange-results), the solution is to set the `IfModifiedSince` property to prevent the default caching behaviour like this:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.Now;
```

You could also check on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.ifmodifiedsince(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.